# Vectorization graphics approach

Tags: vector-graphics

Could you advise,please, what approach to use in following situation:

i'm gonna draw simple comics and ,as I see ,there are two ways:

1. make hand pic. ,scan it and vectorize with Corel Trace or some other tracer (don't know exactly yet)
   or
2. use graphics tablet,if it saves vector graphics;

So, the problem is to get quite good vector output from handmade pic.

Your opinions and experiences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I've done it before:

1. pencil sketch
2. scan
3. Adobe Illustrator -> select image -> Live Trace.  I start with the comic setting.  Tweak threshold, blur, and path to get the image you want.  Don't click strokes; fills scale much better.
4. Convert to Live Paint.  Coloring is trivial.

In this image, my Live Trace wasn't quite closing some gaps so I went back and redrew some lines.  The white dots are touch ups with Fireworks, post-scan, to make the Live Trace more accurate.  There's probably a way to do this with Illustrator, but I'm a novice.

(Please refrain from upvoting based on this incredible display of fine art.)

[image]

I've tried a Wacom Graphite 2 drawing tablet but it was a little slippery and sensitive and required some kind of drawing adjustment for me to get used to.  Plus, I couldn't draw as fast as I can with pencil and paper.

Comment: +1 - I just couldn't help myself. Such beauty, such talent ;-)

Comment: Uhmm, ... what is it exactly ? :-)

Comment: Is it a hypertoad?

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to be a toad.  I was discussing them during dinner and drew it on an envelope.