# Photoshop/Illustrator: generate vector graphic from bitmap

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vectorization graphics approach](https://superuser.com/questions/65655/vectorization-graphics-approach)

Folks,
Photoshop newbie here with what I think is a simple question, but clearly, I am not searching for the right keywords on Google.

I have a hand-sketched pattern that I have scanned into a (bitmap) image. It is a crisp black and white image. I would like for a way to get Photoshop (or Illustrator) to detect the edges and extract paths from it, thereby converting it into a vector graphic.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

-Raj

Comment: Or http://superuser.com/questions/124204/is-there-software-that-will-convert-a-jpg-to-a-vector-format

Comment: Or http://superuser.com/questions/79172/how-to-convert-poor-quality-bitmap-image-to-vector, though I find Inkscape woefully unintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using the 'trace' function in Illustrator: there's a tutorial [here](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/illustrator/ss/sflivetrace.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Illustrator then use the tools built into it for doing exactly what you're doing. But if you don't have / want to use the Adobe software there are several free alternatives:

[Potrace](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Potrace) is Free (as in FOSS) vectorisation software, these days it comes as a plugin for the free vector graphics package [Inkscape](http://wiki.inkscape.org/)

The brilliant commercial / open source vector graphics package Xara is available [free for Linux](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/), it has an excellent built-in tracing tool (and it kicks illustrator's 4rse for speed and ease of use)

Other free vectorisation software includes [AutoTrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) and [Deliniate](http://delineate.sourceforge.net/).

Also there's a free web app called vector magic [here](http://vectormagic.com/home), they sell a desktop version as well.

-stib

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is any way to easily/automatically "vectorize" a raster image in Photoshop or Illustrator.  There does appear to be an online utility that offers two trial conversions before you have to pay, then they want $7.95/month, which is probably quite excessive for individual use.

Check out http://vectormagic.com/home -- if you're just doing one image, that should do the trick for you.